# How can i use for loop with String Array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

i found errors when compile the mentioned source .
i want to for loop to string array increase with numberer array. like as

```
1 + st = 1st;
2 + nd = 2nd;
 3 + rd = 3rd;
```

my code is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int value=1;
int ivalue;
int sum=0;
int average;
int x,y;
int count=0;
string A[5]={"st","nd","rd","th","th"};


cout << "Enter loop limit : "; cin >> value ;
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

for( x=0;x<=value-1;x++){
    for (x=0;x<=A[5];x++)
        cout << "Enter "<<x+1<<A[0]<<" value : "; cin >> ivalue;
        sum=sum+ivalue;
        count++;




  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following code work for you?

```
int main(){
    int value=1;
    int ivalue;
    int sum=0;
    int count=0;
    string A[5]={"st","nd","rd","th","th"};


    cout << "Enter loop limit : "; cin >> value ;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    for(int x = 0; x <= value - 1; x++){
        cout << "Enter "<<x+1<<A[x]<<" value : "; 
        cin >> ivalue; 
        sum=sum+ivalue;
        count++;
    }

    cout<<"Sum:"<<sum<<endl;
}
```